# Selenium Regex: Match literal string with dynamic date

Tags: regex, selenium

I'm writing some Selenium tests and need to confirm the presence of a text string that has dynamic date and currency components.

Example: "This is the date dd/dd/dd and this is the amount $ddd.dd."

Is this possible with the Selenium regex implementation?

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: what is _Selenium regex implementation_?

Comment: I'm using the webdriver - maybe that's the rub? I'm not seeing a way to test a string against a regex pattern. I ended up just finding the element with webdriver, then handing it's text off to NUnint's StringAssert.IsMatch method to confirm the text.

Comment: And that is how it should be done

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken selenium supports the full power of javascript

- Date dd/mm/yyyy

  01/01/1900 through 31/12/2099

  Matches invalid dates such as February 31st

  Accepts dashes, spaces, forward slashes and dots as date separators

  ```
  (0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)[0-9]{2}
  ```
- Currency

  ```
  \$\d*(\.\d*)?
  ```

Comment: So, just find an element you want to test, call [`getText()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText%28%29) on it, and then [search for](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) this regex in the String returned.