# Selenium selector: Issue when using text() in xpath

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have html form which has below template:

```
<div class="order__details">
                    <p><span class="label">Order Status:</span>In Progress</p>
                </div>
```

I want to get the XPath for "In Progress" Text; the text is dynamic

I tried: //div[@class='order__details']/p/text()

But it gives me error:

OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//div[@class='order__details']/p/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element

Comment: Do you have any code you tried?

Comment: //span[@class='label'][contains(.,'Order Status:')] but this is not fetching in progress text

Comment: The text that you search is not within your span tag, that's why your xpath fails.

Comment: Don't you need `text()` in your Xpath? https://devhints.io/xpath

Comment: Yes text in my xpath

Comment: No.. text() is a function missing from your Xpath expression. So you need the text within the node. You are targettng the node not the content without text()

Comment: Why are you using XPath? There is almost certainly a better tool to be doing this with. For example [HtmlAgillityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) or [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/) depending on your use case. The problem with XPath is that it's designed for XML and HTML isn't XML

Comment: What Selenium function do you use to apply your xpath?

Answer (score 0):

The text that you search is not within your span tag, that's why your xpath fails. This xpath expression should serve your needs:

```
"//div[@class='order__details']/p/text()"
```

Comment: Thank you @lab9 - this XPath "//div[@class='order__details']/p/text()" worked

Comment: But it gave me this exception: OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//div[@class='order__details']/p/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.

Comment: @PS_1, this seems to be a problem around what selenium expects the result to be. But I'm not a selenium expert.

Comment: thanks @lab9 - I have changed the question since you helped in xpath now the issue revolves around selector

Comment: the comment underneath (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971209/selenium-regex-match-literal-string-with-dynamic-date) suggests that in Selenium you might be successful with the getText() function. In that case, you would just use "//div[@class='order__details']/p" as the xpath and apply getText() on that.

Comment: it gives me this value ""ORDER STATUS:IN PROGRESS""

Comment: as a subsequent step, because you're in the javascript context you might just use `/(.+):(.+)$/.exec(yourvar)[2]` on the variable `yourvar` that holds your string "ORDER STATUS: some value". It might not be the most elegant solution, but an option as long as you're lacking a one-shot solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following XPath expressions :

```
//span[@class='label'][contains(.,'Order Status:')]/following::text()[1][normalize-space()]

//div[@class="order__details"]/p/text()[normalize-space()]
```

Output : `In Progress`

EDIT :  For Selenium, get the text with :

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[@class='order__details'][./p[contains(.,'Order Status:')]]/p")).Text;
```

Comment: I can use but problem will be that - it is giving me exception that it is not a element since we are fetching text

Comment: OK. Post is edited with a Selenium solution. Catch the element containing the text, then use `.Text`.

Comment: Done that but still same error: OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException: 'invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//div[@class='order__details']/p/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.

XPath: WebElement label_OrderStatus = "//div[@class='order__details']/p/text()"

 return label_OrderStatus.element.Text;

Comment: Still it gives me value as "ORDER STATUS:IN PROGRESS"

Comment: Once you get the text, you can substring with something like : `result.Split(':').Last()` to output `In Progress`.